# Using React-Navigation with react-native-web throws me error because it cannot import web related module

Tags: javascript, react-navigation, react-native-web

I am using react native web with react-navigation. I am getting this error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './PlatformHelpers' in '/home/vineet/projects/jm-agent-web/node_modules/react-navigation/lib'
```

I am getting this error because these files are present: PlatfomrHelpers.ios.js,  PlatfomrHelpers.android.js,  PlatfomrHelpers.web.js. But there is no PlatfomrHelpers.js.

So my ES6 importing system is not able to import PlatfomrHelpers.web.js for the import name ' PlatfomrHelpers' in react-native-web.

How to solve this?

Comment: hey, did you solve it?

Comment: @Cherniv - Yes. Please check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to share the solution that I implemented and its a really easy one.

The problem can be solved by telling webpack to prioritize import of .web.js file.

I went into my webpack.config.js file. Inside top level 'resolve' property I can add '.web.js' as an element in the 'extensions' array. The following code solved it:

```
extensions: ['.web.js', '.js', '.json', '.jsx']
```

Now my webpack is picking up 'PlatfomrHelpers.web.js' for the statement:

```
import 'PlatformHelpers'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that react-navigation distinguishes between `PlatformHelpers.native.js` and `PlatformHelpers.web.js` for native and web. With react native you usually have `.ios.js` and `.android.js` files to distinguish between your platform, react-navigation also targets web though. The simplest solution is to teach your flow config to also handle `.native.js` files for native and `.web.js` for react native web.

Therefore add this to your `.flowconfig` in the `[options]` section:

```
module.file_ext=.web.js
```

Or for standard react native:

```
module.file_ext=.native.js
```